# Spark SQL join really lazy?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

I'm performing an inner join between, say, 8 dataframes, all coming from the same parent. Sample code:

```
// read parquet 
val readDF = session.read.parquet(...)
// multiple expensive transformations are performed over readDF, making its DAG grow

// repartition + cache
val df = readDF.repartition($"type").cache

val df1 = df.filter($"type" === 1)
val df2 = df.filter($"type" === 2)
val df3 = df.filter($"type" === 3)
val df4 = df.filter($"type" === 4)
val df5 = df.filter($"type" === 5)
val df6 = df.filter($"type" === 6)
val df7 = df.filter($"type" === 7)
val df8 = df.filter($"type" === 8)

val joinColumns = Seq("col1", "col2", "col3", "col4")
val joinDF = df1
  .join(df2, joinColumns)
  .join(df3, joinColumns)
  .join(df4, joinColumns)
  .join(df5, joinColumns)
  .join(df6, joinColumns)
  .join(df7, joinColumns)
  .join(df8, joinColumns)
```

Unexpectedly, the `joinDF` sentence is taking a long time. Join is supposed to be a transformation, not an action.

Do you know what's happening? Is this a use case for checkpointing?

Notes: 
 - `joinDF.explain` shows a long DAG lineage.
 - using Spark 2.3.0 with Scala

Comment: Unable to reproduce on my side. To build up the DAG is a matter of milliseconds. I've seen however similar issue, usually it happens when you have performed a lot of transformations beforehand, i.e. in your comment `// multiple transformations are performed over readDF, making its DAG grow`, especially joins and `withColumn` statements tend to make the DAG grow heavily, making the planning preparations slower.

Comment: So what is the question really? Title is nowhere.

Comment: The repartition is obviated by the joinColumns subsequently

Comment: @thebluephantom, the question is: is join really lazy? Regarding the repartition, it's supposed to help the filters only, not the join. As you said, join repartition will be automatically optimised by Tungsten.

Comment: Hard to follow. JOIN is not an Action, so it is lazy. Explain is done where I am just like that.

Comment: Optimization means doing work as well.

Answer (score 0):

RDD JOIN, SPARK SQL JOIN are known as a Transformation. I ran this with no issue on DataBricks Notebook, but I am not privy to " ...// multiple expensive transformations are performed over readDF, making its DAG grow .... May be there is an Action there.

Comment: The code is just a sample. I'm sure I don't have actions in the "expensive transformations" - if that was the case, it would be slower in that step, not in the join.

Comment: So if not, then the answer remains and JOIN is still a Transformation.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, checkpointing seems to fix the long running join. It now behaves as a transformation, returning faster. So, I conclude that the delay was related to the large DAG lineage.

Also, the subsequent actions are now faster.

Comment: Must admit find it hard to follow, this line vs the actual question title.